# Tables of multiples in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I would like to print a table that print rows*columns in that many rows and columns, with the beginning of each column incrementing by one and that row being multiples of the first number. For example: table(3,4)

```
1 2 3 4
2 4 6 8 
3 6 9 12
```

Here is my code so far. It's currently going by ones, and I don't know how to make each row be a multiple of the first number. Thank you.

```
def table(rows, columns):
    for i in range(rows):
        print(*range(1+i*columns, 1+(i+1)*columns))
        for h in range(rows%rows):
            print(*range(1+h*columns%rows, 1+(h+1)*columns))
```

Answer (score 0):

You should iterate over a range of rows and a range of columns, and output their products:

```
def table(rows, columns):
    for i in range(1, rows + 1):
        for h in range(1, columns + 1):
            print(i * h, end=' ')
        print()
```

so that:

```
table(3, 4)
```

would output:

```
1 2 3 4 
2 4 6 8 
3 6 9 12
```